# apt-get can't overwrite file of already existing file of another package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I'm having problems with installing some applications.
unity-tweak-tool I installed the program crashes after installation.
I do not know what to do?

```
apt-get -f install
Reading package lists ... Completed
Creating hierarchies relationship
Reading state information ... Completed
Correcting dependencies between packages ... Completed
Will install the following additional packages.
  account-plugin-google
Install package * New * following.
  account-plugin-google
0 upgraded, install a new one, remove and 0 not upgraded to 0.
Install or remove, not one.
To download packages 0 B / 3,474 B.
After this operation, Require more disk space 68.6 kB.
Do you want to continue anyway? [Y / n] y
(Reading database ... 355310 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing break ... / Account-plugin-google_0.12 + 15.04.20150415.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
There are account-plugin-google (0.12 + 15.04.20150415.1-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: An error occurred while processing the archive. /var/cache/apt/archives/account-plugin-google_0.12+15.04.20150415.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
 Trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service' Which is in the package. kde-config-telepathy-accounts 15.04.1-0ubuntu1 ~ ubuntu15.04 ~ ppa1 as well.
An error occurred while processing.
 /var/cache/apt/archives/account-plugin-google_0.12+15.04.20150415.1-0ubuntu2_all.deb
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1).
```

Comment: You have a conflicting package installed. Remove that one if you want this new one. Probably "kde-config-telepathy-accounts 15.04.1-0ubuntu1 ~ ubuntu15.04 ~ ppa1". It conflicts with "account-plugin-google".

Comment: I tried to remove unity-tweak-tool, but not deleted. And this time, I can not install any more.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I have a System76 laptop where I had installed the Kubuntu desktop.

The problem with apt-get is it tries to be a little too magical here.  You need something more low-level to remove the Ubuntu packages that rely on the package that provides the conflict.  I don't use Unity, so this works for me:

```
sudo dpkg -r \
  account-plugin-google unity-scope-gdrive unity-scope-gdocs
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get ugrade
```

Please let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Now i use Synaptic package manager to uninstall unity-tweak-tool  successfully.